# How can I view my HAML emails in the browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, browser, haml

I am currently writing some transaction-based emails in my Rails app for things like signup confirmation, etc.  What I want to do however, is to be able to see what the email looks like in the browser or somewhere as I am making it.  Since I am using HAML, I am unable to simply open the file in the browser.

How could I set it up so that I can view my HAML user_mailer code in the browser?  If that is not possible, what alternative could I use just for emails?

Answer (score 2):

The following gem works well for me: https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Comment: how can i look at my emails while i am making it without having to send an email everytime

Comment: The gem cannot to that. But you can send an email using the Rails console and view the email in the browser. This is the most efficient development cycle I know of when editing email templates.